# How to execute a query taken from views in custom module

Tags: views

Please don't suggest query builder, this is the single query I need run from my custom module with passing arguments.

I create a View with desire fields and copy/past the query in phpMyAdmin the query is not showing the actual values for columns instead showing value as NODE :(

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean it contains something like `SELECT 'node' as entity_type`? If so, that's normal

Comment: It is hard to work out what your exact problem is without more information. Can you add the full query to your original post as that may help work out your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Goto admin/structure/views/settings and enable the setting

> Show other queries run during render during live preview

[image]

As the help text for the setting reads, probably during the view rendering time there are some changes that could be happening. Enabling this setting will give you an insight into what is happening.

Comment: It didn't work, tnx btw